# docker Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm trying to create docker machine host using the following command in fedora OS version 25.

```
docker-machine create -driver=virtualbox host01
```

I get below error while executing the command.

```
Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is \"WARNING: 
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. 
Either there is no module available for the current kernel (4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64) or it failed to load.
Please try load the kernel module by executing as root
dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64            akmods --kernels 4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 && systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service 
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\\n5.1.26r117224\". 
Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org"
```

I have already virtualbox latest version installed. Running the command suggested by

```
 sudo dnf install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 akmods --kernels 4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 && systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
```

I got the below error

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:48:35 ago on Thu Aug 17 22:38:47 2017.
Package akmods-0.5.6-7.fc25.noarch is already installed, skipping.
No package --kernels available.
No package 4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 available.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you using docker-machine on fedora? why not just use docker CE?

Comment: Also instead of get Virtialbox from packages get it directly from the website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this problem and for this I upgrade Virtual box to 5.2 using following commands. This [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/virtualbox-reached-5-2-major-release-how-to-install/) help me

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.1
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Had the same issue on **Ubuntu 18.04**, **VirtualBox 6.0** and *Secure Boot* disabled. This answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, in 2022 such problem still exists. So for those who use last build (now it is virtualBox-6.1.32-149290-Win), try to use version that starts with prefix 5. But not all '5' versions work. For example, for me worked only version 5.2.42  while versions: 5.2.18, 5.2.20, 5.2.44 didn't work

Helped for win 11 x64